# using a parameter in mongoDb .find() query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, http, get

This works, but once I change the 123 to `req.params.userId`, I obtain an empty array from the `GET` request.

```
router.get("/:userId", async (req, res) => {
  const posts = await loadPostCollection();
  console.log(req.params.userId) //>>>123
  const info = await posts
    .find({
      userInfo: {
        userId: 123, //req.params.userId doesn't work
        notes: []
      }
    })
    .toArray();
  res.send(await info);
});
```

edit: the question was not how to convert string to num or num to string, but rather help with finding out what's wrong with the code. Therefore, not duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I got it, req.params.userId is a string while userId is expecting a number.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of string and number. Try converting the req.params.userId to number and it should work!